# How to watermark once with Sox command

Tags: sox

Hello I am trying to use the Sox command for watermarking an audio Watermark into an audio file and I would like to watermark it once. I mean if for example , I have an audio file of 1256 seg duration and I have a watermark audio file I would like how to set the watermark audio in an specific time , for example 135 seconds.
Any idea on how to do that with Sox or any other tool.
Thanks.
Gorka

Comment: do you want do "merge" the watermark or to "insert" it?

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a `watermark.wav` at 135s (untested):

```
sox "|sox  in.wav -p trim 0 135" watermark.wav "|sox in.wav -p trim 135" out.wav
```

This means: `out.wav = concatenate( in.wav[0:135] , watermark , in.wav[135:end])`

Comment: I have executed the command before and obtain the following result :

sox FAIL formats: can't open input file ` |sox Imp.wav -p trim 5': Invalid argument

I have googled a solution but I have not found anyone.
I have also tried to find the comand concatenate but I have not found any way on how to use that comand in windows. Any ideas ? Thanks. Gorka

Comment: @Gorka, the solution was design for linux or similar. The way windows treats "..."  and sub-process  is probably different... (a very similar situation works find in linux).

Comment: Hello I have tested that solution and when the watermark is added in a specific time , the video stops and the watermark starts being played. Whan I mean i that the user must not notice about the noise which has been played